# Got kick for killing team mate in CS:GO but didn't fire a shot that round

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Something was wrong with a competitive game in CS:GO:

After I have died, a member of my team was killed by me, although I was already spectating the player in question.

There was a lot of smoke and I wasn’t paying much attention; so I did see who killed him, however I did get there severe warning you get when you kill someone “kill 3 more team mates…” I was willing to overlook this and just carried on the game. My Team suggest that say to throw it a spawn so they think we are camped there. I think it’s not worth the effort of not doing it and getting shouted at so I go and waste $50. Ones done I head to bomb A (inferno) my mini map say that my whole team is still at spawn but I don’t really care. But then I get kick for killing too many of my team mates. I haven’t fired a shot all round all I did was throw that decoy graded.

So my question is what did I do? How can I make a team kill although I just threw a decoy in the whole round?

Comment: Please edit this into something a bit more coherent if you want this question to be re-opened.

Comment: What killed your team mate is the explotion of a decoy.

When a decoy(grenade for 50$) is thrown and lands, it makes the sound of your weapon for 15 seconds. After this time it explodes and gives around 5 damage in a tiny radius.

So a team mate with low HP probably waited on your thrown decoy for explotion in order to get you kicked by the automatic kick system.

Comment: The question is legit actually although it seems pretty unclear if you don't play CS:GO due to the lack of correct grammar and spelling. I corrected the crucial parts so that it should be understandable. The answer is the comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Every grenade does damage- especially in this case when they hit people. They don't damage much, but it still counts as friendly fire, so be careful where you throw your grenades.

There is a nice video showing it, more can be found by googling "CS:GO flash hit kill":

Comment: On video, kills start at 0:20. Disclosure: Not the owner of the video.

Comment: He says that he made the kill when he was already spectating, can't be a flashbang so, but only the explotion of a decoy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you throw a decoy?

Decoy nades explode after a while, and though they only do something like 2 or 3 damage, it is still enough to be lethal in rare circumstances - even to teammates.

It is possible a teammate had 3 HP and stepped on the decoy when it blew up - killing him in the process.